# Couldn't see my Popup window

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup, asp.net-ajax, modal-dialog

I given my coding for a modal popup using AJAX. The problem is when I click the button, the popup is not displaying instead, it is just blinking once. Look at my code and tell me what is the problem with it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Login</asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="241px" Style="display:none" >
    <table style="border-style: inherit; border-width: thin; width:100%;">
        <tr>
             <td class="style2">Username</td>
             <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">Password</td>
            <td class="style1"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Signin" />               </td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxTK:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                           TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
                           PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                           OkControlID="Button1" 
                           CancelControlID="Button1"
                           BackgroundCssClass="modepop">
</ajaxTK:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: I think your page is postback by any event,do you have only this code in page? try to set OnClientClick="javascript:return false;" of login button.

Comment: @MikiShah,  I doesn't have anyother script (or) code...this is the only code in my page.

Comment: Thank u @MikiShah, it works for me... Thnk u very much.!!!!!!

Comment: Can you tell me the use of this OnClientClick="javascript:return false".... Why we have specify this property ???

Comment: @Elango_Thanumalayan Because the button causes a postback to the server, but you are using a client control; a client control does not retain whether it should show when it hits the server.  So you need to prevent the postback in order to make that happen, thus the purpose of this code.

Comment: Thankx @Brian...for your support.